# get Month and Year in Colums // Mysql

Tags: mysql, cumulative-sum

I have the following Select in Mysql, which enables me to list an amount for each customer by month. It works fine as it is.
I would like to have in each column not only by month but also adding the corresponding year (instead of 'Jan' in Col 1, 'Jan 2015', 'Feb 2015' in Col 2, etc...)

Also, As a first line, how could I group the sum of the corresponding column to have this

```
             Jan-2015   Feb-2015   Mar-2015 
 Total           1000       1600     ...
 Customer1        100        800
 Customer2        900        600
 Customer3          0        200
```

How could I achieve this? I can have a Total line with PHP, but getting it in a Select would save me a lot of time...

Here is my initial select

```
SELECT
 Customers,
 sum(if(month(Date) = 1, Total_Deposits, 0))  AS Jan,
 sum(if(month(Date) = 2, Total_Deposits, 0))  AS Feb,
 sum(if(month(Date) = 3, Total_Deposits, 0))  AS Mar,
 sum(if(month(Date) = 4, Total_Deposits, 0))  AS Apr,
 sum(if(month(Date) = 5, Total_Deposits, 0))  AS May,
 sum(if(month(Date) = 6, Total_Deposits, 0))  AS Jun,
 sum(if(month(Date) = 7, Total_Deposits, 0))  AS Jul,
 sum(if(month(Date) = 8, Total_Deposits, 0))  AS Aug,
 sum(if(month(Date) = 9, Total_Deposits, 0))  AS Sep,
 sum(if(month(Date) = 10, Total_Deposits, 0)) AS Oct,
 sum(if(month(Date) = 11, Total_Deposits, 0)) AS Nov,
 sum(if(month(Date) = 12, Total_Deposits, 0)) AS `Dec`
FROM Online_customer_activity_v2
where Date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-12-31'
Group by Customers
ORDER by sum(`Online_customer_activity_v2`.`Total_Deposits`) DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Thanks to everyone in advance for your tips!

Comment: What you need is called Pivoting table. Look here on SO there are plenty questions answered on it.

Comment: This one for instance is a well written answer on DBA forum: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/46085/42478

Comment: Thanks jose! Will have a look at this!